# New blank page after pdfinclude?

Tags: pdf, page-breaking, pdfpages

I'm working on a latex document in which I have to include a automatically generated pdf from my university as the titelpage. Directly after the titelpage, the table of content (and obviously the rest of the thesis) follow. However, I want there to be a blank page between the pdf and the table of content, because I have to print my thesis double sided and all the new chapters, the table of content, bibliography, etc. have to start on the right page. Without the blank page inbetween, they all start on the left page.

How can I put a page in there? The \newpage command doesn't seem to work, since its a \includepdf from the package pdfpages.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone else out there wondering, after some digging I found a fairly simple solution to this. I just used

```
\clearpage \mbox{} \thispagestyle{empty} \clearpage
```

after the \includepdf command so Latex clears the page, buts an empty mbox on the new pages and clears that one again. I now got a blank page inbetween, which I declared an empty pagestyle so there won't be any numbering in the top corner!

Comment: You probably can also use \cleardoublepage (assuming that you are using the twoside class option). \includepdf is not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

```
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
\newpage
```

newpage can be generated with the use of \mbox{}. Use this where there is a need for blank pages.

Ref: [Latex how to insert a blank or empty page](https://www.math-linux.com/latex-26/faq/latex-faq/article/latex-how-to-insert-a-blank-or-empty-page-with-or-without-numbering-thispagestyle-newpage-usepackage-afterpage)